# Is completable future interrupted or does buttonView has some kind of timeout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, completable-future, ui-thread

I am using CF to get List of  Exercises. When the user clicks on the button the Text turns Gray and button is not clickable anymore:
[image]

so the button turns gray but the `setEnabled(false);` call causes the Problem, when I set the Breakpoint
and when the `setEnabled(false);` line is to be executed the Debugger simply stops and the Program continues running as if the Thread is interrupted and the control is handed back to the main Thread (or the UI Thread), when I click away and come back then the `setEnabled(false);` is also  performed and the button is not clickable anymore, the button is also not clickable after the click has been performed but the view is simply not updated so it can be visible, so why does "setTextColor(Color.GRAY); " doesnt make any problems but setEnabled does.

Here is the CF call

```
client.userReacted(exercises.get(position),reaction,mainActivityReference.userReactionsListLocal, mainActivityReference.reactionsThread)
                    .thenAcceptAsync((reactionMap)->{
                        if (reactionMap!=null){
                            mainActivityReference.userReactionsListLocal=reactionMap;
                            setColorsAndCounterAfterReaction(mainActivityReference.userReactionsListLocal, position, holder);
                            CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{LoggedInUserHolder.updateOrSaveReactionListLocally(mainActivityReference.userReactionsListLocal);});
                        }
                        else
                            Helpers.msgToDisplayAsSnackbar(mainActivityReference.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                    "Es tut uns leid, aber aufgrund Verbindungsproblemen ist die Abgabe einer Reaktion nicht möglich",3000,7,Gravity.TOP);
                    }, mainActivityReference.reactionsThread);
```

inside `setColorsAndCounterAfterReaction` method is where the change is happening:

```
if(reaction.contains(REACT_FAVORITE_KEY)){
                holder.to_favorite.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                holder.to_favorite.setEnabled(false);-> the buttonView is not updated, have to exit the view and come back to see the change
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
activityInstance.runOnUiThread(()->{setColorsAndCounterAfterReaction(mainActivityReference.userReactionsListLocal, position, holder);});
```

solves the Problem, hope it will help somene some day